# Python. Import a function and then modified it. Later returns error in the same python session

Tags: python

I have two python scripts, one has all functions I have defined (**functions.py**) and the other only runs those functions (**running_functions.py**).
I imported the functions into **running_functions** script using `from functions import*`

My problem is when I ran **running_functions** into python console using `execfile('running_functions.py')` at first worked like a charm, but if I don't close the python session and do some modifications into one function in **functions.py** (for example changing the number of parameters that `getLabels()` takes (from 4 to 5)) saved then and then I ran again **running_functions.py** with the same comand or when I called `getLabels()` I get the error:

**With execfile()**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "running_functions.py", line 82, in <module>
    predict_labels = getLabels(pred_labels, ids_tr ,labels_tr,filenames_tr, filenames_ts)
TypeError: getLabels() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

**Calling the function**

```
>>> predict_labels = getLabels(pred_labels, ids_tr ,labels_tr,filenames_tr, filenames_ts)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getLabels() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

To get it work again I have to close python session and then run again `execfile()` or rename `functions.py` or do little pythons scripts with modified function.

This is very annoying because all the code takes around 10 or 15 minutes and I don't like have a lot of little scripts. So, how can I avoid this error?
I wouldn't like to close every time the session and wouldn't like to use in each function pickle module. Is it wrong the way I imported the functions? And why python returns this error? Sorry for this silly questions

Comment: I strongly recommend just restarting Python. There are ways to edit files you've imported and use the changed versions, but they all have caveats and messy edge cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend skimming over [how python imports work](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).  In general it's considered bad practice to use glob imports like `from module import *`.  It's not transparent and makes it difficult to take advantage of `reload`.

I would recommend rewriting your code to do the following :

```
import functions

functions.getLabels(...)
```

and then after you change getLabels or something, you can from the shell run the following :

```
reload(functions)
```

and that will re-import your changes without having to restart the python kernel.

Comment: [Python 3.X: `importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)